# Handshake Error When Debugging Mono Droid for Android Phone

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

Every so often (1 in 3 maybe) times I deploy to my phone to test my Android app (which is built using Mono Droid, the professional personal paid for license), I get the following error below. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and my phone is an Android Samsung Epic 4G.

Error initializing the debugger: Mono.Debugging.Soft.ConnectionException: Could not connect to the debugger. ---> System.IO.IOException: DWP Handshake failed.

Server stack trace:
    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Connect() ...

After the error pops up, my app shows up blank on my phone for a minute and then shows a dialog to force close it. Is there anyone who has seen this before or knows of why it happens?

Comment: One of the guys in the MonoDroid forum mentioned trying this: Reinstall the adb-driver for the device. I believe this is the USB driver to connect to your computer. So I will give this a try and let everyone know how it goes.

Comment: Still haven't found the cause of this - only happens when I have the mode set to Debug and it's still only every once in a while...

Answer (score 0):

Changing target to "AnyCPU" fixed it for me.